# Blank input to a defined function in Python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, slice

I have a defined function to slice a dataframe and do some analysis like this

```
def df_slice(startrow,endrow):
    do something...
    newdf = df[startrow,endrow]
    do something...
return newdf
```

Normally for to analyze the first few rows a df, I can just use

```
df1= df_slice(0,10)
```

But what if I wish to slice the last 5 rows of the dataframe?
so that in the function

```
newdf = df[-5:]
```

I would not use `df1= df_slice(-5,'')` or just leave in blank like `df1= df_slice(-5,)`.

What should I do?

Comment: newdf = df[endrow-startrow-5,endrow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df[startrow, endrow]
```

is equivalent to

```py
df.__getitem__((startrow, endrow))
```

And

```py
df[startrow:]
```

is equivalent to

```py
df.__getitem__(slice(startrow, None))
```

Here is a sample code:

```py
class MyCollection:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item


my_collection = MyCollection()
print(my_collection[1, 2])
print(my_collection[1:])
```

output:

```py
(1, 2)
slice(1, None, None)  # start, stop, step
```

As you noticed, the omitting slice element means `None`.
So you can call

```py
newdf = df_slice(-5, None)
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, just input None as the parameter.